# Java arrays and objects

Tags: java

If arrays are treated as objects in Java and if we have a multidimensional array like an array of integer arrays then is it correct to say that this multidimensional array is also an array of objects?
I am kinda confused as I have read that arrays can hold only two types i.e. either primitives or references so if an array holds an array will it be correct to regard the same a array of objects?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct to say that this multidimensional array is also an array of objects?

Yes, that is correct. An array is an object. So, an array of arrays, is an array of objects.

Comment: Of course that presumes that the arrays have been instantiated, otherwise it could be an array of null references.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct because arrays are objects

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not treated as objects, they *are* objects.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays are "arrays of arrays". You can get more information here http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D-2.html

So it is also possible to create multi-dimensional arrays which are not square and so on

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. When we say "array of objects" in Java we generally mean "array of *references to* objects", so when we have something like

```
int[][] x = ...;
```

then `x` is an array holding references to `int[]`s (i.e. int arrays).

---

From the [JLS §10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1):

> The component type of an array may itself be an array type. The components of such an array may contain references to subarrays. If, starting from any array type, one considers its component type, and then (if that is also an array type) the component type of that type, and so on, eventually one must reach a component type that is not an array type; this is called the element type of the original array, and the components at this level of the data structure are called the elements of the original array.
>
> There are some situations in which an element of an array can be an array: if the element type is `Object` or `Cloneable` or `java.io.Serializable`, then some or all of the elements may be arrays, because any array object can be assigned to any variable of these types.